# Wordpress link and content

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm creating a menu for wordpress, but when I click on the permalink the content stays the same. And my second dropdown does not work eather. The problem is that on my section where the content needs to be it not shows. The content just takes the last message and not the post i select on the menu.

https://i.gyazo.com/1698056c27baa40768659d2edab5e3d9.png
This is how it stays even if i click an other post.

```
  <?php
  get_header();
  ?>
  <div class="menu">

    <div>
        <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><h1>Documentatie</h1></a>
    </div>


      <?php $cats = get_categories();

      foreach ($cats as $cat) {
        $cat_id= $cat->term_id;
        echo "<div class='dropdown'>";
        echo "<button onclick='myFunction()' class='dropbtn'>".$cat->name."</button>";
        echo "<div id='myDropdown' class='dropdown-content'>";

        query_posts("cat=$cat_id&post_per_page=100");

    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

     <button class="dropbutton"><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></button>

  <?php endwhile;
?>
</div>
</div>
<?php
   else :
    echo "<p>Geen content gevonden</p>";
  endif;
   wp_reset_postdata();
 }
?>
</div>
  <div class="content">
   <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
   <div class="wpcontent"><?php the_content(); ?> </div>
 </div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your code sample is incomplete. You also haven't made it clear what exactly you are trying to achieve and your question "does anyone know more about wordpress...?" is way too broad.  You need to be specific and clarify what you're trying to achieve, provide a full code sample and give us any error messages you're getting.

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: That is much better and should be easier for a php expert to help you now.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: First thing - you have multiple IDs with the same name "myDropdown" - that's invalid HTML and probably one part that's causing trouble.

Comment: Second thing - you're not passing any argument to your myFunction() - meaning, that every click calls the function and does the same thing.
Also, no idea what classList is - is that a plugin?

Comment: I coppied it from w3school

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my other 2 comments and proposed solution below, this is not a WP issue you're facing, it's JS/jQuery

```
    echo "<div class='dropdown'>";
    echo "<button onclick='myFunction(" . $cat->slug . ")' class='dropbtn btn-" . $cat->slug . "'>".$cat->name."</button>";
    echo "<div id='myDropdown' class='dropdown-content'>";
```

And:

```
function myFunction(cat_slug) {
   $('.btn-' + cat_slug).show();
}
```

Try that, should work :)

Comment: Have you tried this solution? did it work? if so, please accept the answer. Thank you